# Regular expression to match a number range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having problem with JavaScript regular expressions. I want to match real numbers form 1 to 5. Precission is in two digits. My code is but it doesnt work.

```
function validate_prosjek(nmb)
{
    var pattern= new RegExp(/[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]|5\.00/);

    return pattern.test(nmb);
}
```

It recognizes real numbers higher than 5.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Please note that none of that has anything to do with jQuery, this is all Javascript functionality. This information should help you search for what you're looking for next time.

Comment: Works on my machine.  Tested with http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @RobertHarvey it _can't_ work - it's not restrictive enough and will fail to ignore any extra numeric digits on either end of the number.

Comment: @MikeM yes, you're right (sigh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "anchor" your regexp with `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the string, respectively:

```
var pattern = /^([1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]|5\.00)$/;
```

You also need to escape the `.` because it's a special character in regexps, and there's no need to call `new RegExp` if the regexp is already in `/.../` synax.

Comment: @MikeM ok, so it does - I found a test case where it didn't work.

Comment: /^[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]|^5\.00$/

Comment: Final version.Works fine. Your fail on cases where second digit is 5 and number is grater than 10, such as 15.00 25.00 and so long

Comment: @BodoHombah no, like Ansgar and MikeM pointed out, you need a group around the two alternatives.

Comment: the version that's been there for the last five minutes does not have that problem.  You _must_ have the `()` group.

Comment: It works fine. I just tested it. I cant find case in whic it doesnt work.

Comment: ah, you put an extra `^` in?  Yeah, that works too.  The group is the more "standard" way of doing this, though.

Comment: @MikeM You are right. What abou this /^[1-4]\.[0-9][0-9]$|^5\.00$/