# Javascript Form validation | set a specific input format

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that has an input field requiring user to enter only any of the following three options:

1. Number like 150
2. Number starting with one letter (which must be N, not case sensitive) like N150
3. Number ending with one letter (which must be N, not case sensitive) like 150N

Any other value like:

- 150x will return error message `wrong input`
- x150 will return `wrong input`
- 1N50 will return `wrong position`

Answer (score 0):

The **correct** way to do this is to make an array of valid numbers and then to check if the given text exists on your array.
For example:

```
var validNumbers = [ 150, N150, 150N ]; 
if (validNumbers.indexOf(parseInt(num, 10)) >=0 ) {
    //Match
}
```

You'll need an `indexOf` function for IE:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(needle) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === needle) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
}
```

Comment: The 150, 150N and N150 is just an example, user may input different number like 2000, 1657N, N8 etc

Comment: So you can edit to match with what you want! I just gave you a possible solution!

Comment: Rigth, numbers from (001 - 999) (N001 - N999) (001N-999N), just a  3000 values array :/ . and by the way, *N130* is not #correct# ...

Answer (score 0):

check this answer :

[Regular expression to match a number range in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180060/regular-expression-to-match-a-number-range-in-javascript)

and adjust to your needs, you can easily add the "N" at the end or at the beginning by adding regex part to make accept values like : 
-N150
-150N
-130N
-N130

Answer (score 0):

A non regexapproach (just to show why regex is useful):

```
function test(value){
 //convert to array
 value=value.split("");
 //check the number
 function isnumber(num){
  return num.every(n=>"1234567890".includes(n));
 }

//weve got three possibilities:
  //150
  if(isnumber(value)) return true;

  //N150
  var [n,...rest]=value;
  if(n==="N" && isnumber(rest)) return true;

  //150N
  var n=value.pop();
  return n==="N" && isnumber(value);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kafivecedi/edit?console